# Laravel loggin user out immediately after login

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

## My Code

I have the following routes in Laravel 5.8.

The only public accessible routes, must be `/login`.

```
//web.php

Route::get('/login', function() {
    return view('auth.login', ['loginRequested' => false]);
})->name('login');
Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('process-login');
Route::get('/login/{loginKey}/{loginHash}', 'Auth\LoginController@authenticate');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
    Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
});
```

I then have the following authentication code:

```
// LoginController.php
/**
 * @param string $loginKey
 * @param string $loginHash
 * @param UsersRepository $usersRepository
 * @param ThirdPartyConnect $thirdParty
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector
 */
public function authenticate(string $loginKey, string $loginHash, UsersRepository $usersRepository, ThirdPartyConnect $thirdParty)
{
    try {
        $user = $usersRepository->findUserByHash($loginKey);
        if (md5($user->user_email) !== $loginHash) {
            throw new \Exception('Invalid login hash', 403);
        }

        Auth::login($user);
        $user->details = $thirdParty->getUserDetails($user->user_email);
        Auth::setUser($user);
        return \redirect($this->redirectTo);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return \redirect('login');
    }
}
```

## What do I expect

When I log in, it should redirect to my `$this->redirectTo` where I should have access to the user object via `Auth::user()`.

## What does it do

When I log in, it redirects to `/login`. If I dump user after the `$user->details` call, it has all the info I want on the user. It does not throw an Exception (I've added a `dd($e)` in the catch part of `authenticate`.

It also seems to not set the session time correctly. If I inspect the cookie in chrome, the expiration date is the current date/time and not current date/time + 30mins as per the config file.

## Question

How do I fix this? Is there something I'm missing, is something set up wrong? Why does it redirect back to `/login` and not `$this->redirectTo` as expected?

Comment: Did you try to avoid to update "user data" `$user->details = ...` before redirect?

Comment: @qdequippe I have. If I comment that bit of code out, the same happens.

Comment: just to be sure, did you comment `$user->details = ..` and `Auth::setUser($user)`?

Comment: @qdequippe yes I did. Commented out both lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So found the issue.

My users table's primary key is `user_id`.

My model didn't have this primary key set. So I'm assuming it didn't know who was logged in and destroyed the session.

I added this to my `User` model:

`protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';`